# Accessing local variable within actionPerformed Java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i am trying to reach the value within an int variable from within the actionPerformed class, the integer comes from another class where its passed as an argument "asd" and holds the value "1". I obviously deleted some lines from the code i posted below to make it easier to read but what i ve deleted has nothing to do with the problem im having.
So here, the output i see is;

```
asd

1

1

0

0
```

the last two outputs are from the actionPerformed class, they appear when i click the related button. How can i make it so those 2 outputs are also shown as 1?

```
public class customerAppointmentScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JButton massB,indiB;
public int asd,id;

public customerAppointmentScreen(int asd) {
    System.out.println("asd ");
    System.out.println(asd);
    id=asd;
    System.out.println(id);
    
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    if(e.getSource()==massB) {
        int id=asd;
        System.out.println(asd);
        System.out.println(id);
        //this.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==indiB) {
        
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `id=asd;` should be `this.id=this.asd=asd;` and remove `int id=asd;` line

Comment: I did try this, sadly it still wont work. both print(asd) and printf(id) still show 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with...

```
public int asd,id;

public customerAppointmentScreen(int asd) {
    System.out.println("asd ");
    System.out.println(asd);
    id=asd;
    System.out.println(id);
    
}
```

The parameter `asd` is never assigned to the instance field `asd`, so the instance field remains `0` (`id` on the other hand is equal to the parameter `asd`)

When the `ActionListener` is triggered...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == massB) {
        int id = asd;
        System.out.println(asd);
        System.out.println(id);
        //this.setVisible(false);
    } else if (e.getSource() == indiB) {

        this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

You assign the instance field `asd` value to the local variable `id`, since `asd` is still zero, so is `id`.

The "simple" solution would be to assign the parameter from the constructor to the appropriate instance field OR use the correct instance field in the `ActionListener`, depending on your intentions.

Comment: I dont know where i messed up before but i initially did it like that, declared an int asd2 then asd2=asd, then use asd2 in actionPerformed. It wouldnt work but now it does dunno what was wrong then. Anyway kinda emberrasing problem i had there but thx for the help!